# How to save memory when exporting large files from database to CSV format?

Tags: c#, csv, memory-management, asp.net-core-webapi

I am facing the challenge that I have a SQL created by the user, this SQL I now run via XPO (DevExpress, soon without wrapper directly via NPGSQL). There I already load all data into my memory and transform the result into my own wrapper class.

Now I take my own object and use the CSVHelper to create a CSV file from it. I then return this file to the user via the WebAPI.

Since the SQL query can be 1-2GB in size, the memory consumption increases massively.

What is the best way to prevent this?

I hadn't worked much with streams before and am currently reading up on them. If I have understood correctly, a MemoryStream does not bring me much, because there the data are also loaded directly into memory.

```
[HttpGet("export/data")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExportData(Guid sqlId)
{
    this.OpenConn(); //opens the connection

    string sql = this.GetSql(sqlId);

    using (NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        int val;
        NpgsqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // Logic to create the csv file
        }

        this.CloseConn(); //close the current connection
    }
}
```

I could now create my CSV file using the CSVHelper with a MemoryStream and then return the MemoryStream for the download.

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8);
var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// Logic to create the csv file, with the reader from npgsql
// [...]

return File(ms, "text/csv", "export.csv");
```

If I have understood this correctly, this does not bring me many advantages, since I have stored the data in a MemoryStream and thus the memory is filled anyway.
What is the best way to deal with this? Write the CSV file in a temporary directory on disk and then return it?
I could access an S3Bucket here for example or use my own directory inside of Kubernetes. If I return the stream via file, I can't simply delete the file after a successful transfer, can I? I can not perform a final action? I actually want to transfer the file only for the request and then not have it stored somewhere.

Thanks!

Comment: TBH serving 1-2 GBs files via web API as single chunk is not a great idea in general.

Comment: Fortunately, it is also rather the exception and is rarely used. But I don't want to keep a lot of memory for the rare case that the service doesn't run OutOfMemory. More regularly, it will be a few hundred MB.

Comment: IMHO you should consider writing the data directly to disk and when completly written offer it to download

Comment: I did the same for another use case and stored the data in an S3Bucket. 
In this case, the data should be stored directly in PowerBI and made accessible via a single URL. 
I had also considered whether to resave the data every day and then make the saved files available via the link. However, I wanted to try it first to see if I could manage to transfer the data directly.

Comment: @joey `rather the exception and is rarely used.` then disable it completely. APIs explicitly prevent such cases, forcing clients to use paging or streaming. Neither GraphQL nor OData allow arbitrary result sizes. Both enforce a page size and give multiple paging options to clients.

Comment: @joey `the data should be stored directly in PowerBI` PowerBI can read paged results for OData or GraphQL endpoints already. Although it's a *lot* better to set up an [on-prem data gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-gateway-onprem) instead of manually pushing your data to it.

Comment: @joey another option is to just upload the CSV stored in S3 or local disk. Power BI will copy it internally, not query the data from disk. The [CSV connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/text-csv#connect-to-textcsv-file-from-power-query-online) can load CSVs from both local and web storage

Comment: Currently, I can't page the result in any meaningful way because the SQL is self written by the user (Each customer has its own database, so they can freely access it. This database is also separated from the application database.). I still wanted to look in the future that I can parse and prepare the SQL query so that I can provide LIMITS for paging. But I'm not sure yet how I will do this correctly.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am not the PowerBI professional - a customer had this requirement. I had seen the on-prem data gateway as well. But since we are a SaaS solution, I didn't want to put a gateway in our infrastructure, because then I would need one gateway per customer, if they want to do it also, right?

Comment: Why are you serializing it into SQL queries? You should get users to upload in a better format, and upload it using something like `BeginBinaryImport` https://www.npgsql.org/doc/copy.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to save file locally and stream it.

Alternatively you can try writing directly to `Response.Body` (do not forget to flush) or using [`FileCallbackResult`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/11/streaming-zip-on-aspnet-core.html) approach by Stephen Cleary:

```cs
public class FileCallbackResult : FileResult
{
    private Func<Stream, ActionContext, Task> _callback;

    public FileCallbackResult(string contentType, Func<Stream, ActionContext, Task> callback)
        : base(contentType)
    {
        if (callback == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(callback));
        _callback = callback;
    }

    public override Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        var executor = new FileCallbackResultExecutor(context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>());
        return executor.ExecuteAsync(context, this);
    }

    private sealed class FileCallbackResultExecutor : FileResultExecutorBase
    {
        public FileCallbackResultExecutor(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
            : base(CreateLogger<FileCallbackResultExecutor>(loggerFactory))
        {
        }

        public Task ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, FileCallbackResult result)
        {
            SetHeadersAndLog(context, result, null, false);
            return result._callback(context.HttpContext.Response.Body, context);
        }
    }
}
```

And sample usage:

```
[HttpGet("data")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExportData()
{
    return new FileCallbackResult("text/csv", async (outStream, context) =>
    {
        await using var sw = new StreamWriter(outStream, leaveOpen: true);
        await using var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(sw, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, true);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            await Task.Delay(10);
            csvWriter.WriteRecord(new {Int = i, Text = "Qww" + i});
            await csvWriter.NextRecordAsync();
        }
    })
    {
        FileDownloadName = "qwerty.csv"
    };
}
```

But in general I would recommend to reconsider this approach if possible. If this is an export for some ETL pipeline - for example you can switch to just uploading files to some shared location.

Comment: Oh, very good. That looks like a good option that I can use quickly.

In the next step I should probably limit the size of the file and provide too large files differently.

Answer (score 0):

I maintain a nuget package that can make this very easy: [Sylvan.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Csv](https://github.com/MarkPflug/Sylvan.AspNetCore).

It implements an MVC formatter for CSV using the [Sylvan.Data.Csv](https://github.com/MarkPflug/Sylvan) library. You register the formatter in startup when configuring MVC services:

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(opts => { opts.AddSylvanCsvFormatters(); });
```

In your controller action, you can then return the `DbDataReader` directly, and specify "text/csv" as the content type using the `Produces` attribute:

```
[HttpGet("export/data")]
[Produces("text/csv")]
public async Task<DbDataReader> ExportData()
{
    // no "using" here, connection will be disposed when the reader is closed.
    DbConnection conn = GetConn(); // can be any ADO data provider.
    await conn.OpenAsync();
    using var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from MyData";
    // configure the reader to close the connection when complete.
    return await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
}
```

The implementation is extremely efficient in both CPU and memory usage, and fully async. The response will be streamed to the client, and won't be fully buffered in memory. If using EFCore or another ORM, you can also return an `IEnumerable<T>`, or `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` instead of `DbDataReader`.

The `Sylvan.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Excel` package provides a similar formatter that can return Excel (.xlsx) files. This requires adding the package and registering the formatter `opts.AddSylvanExcelFormatters()`.

You could then add a second endpoint to allow getting the result as an Excel file:

```
[HttpGet("export/data/excel")]
[Produces("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")]
public async Task<DbDataReader> ExportExcel()
{
    // defer to the other endpoint implementation
    return await ExportData();
}
```

The .xlsx response has to be buffered, and cannot be fully streamed due to the structure of the file format. However, the response payload can be significantly smaller than CSV, since the xlsx file format is compressed and re-uses shared strings.